# Finding Arbitrarily Long Word Patterns using Regular Expression in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk

I am using Python 3.6 to find all occurrences of "as" + words + "as" in a text, with a context of three words on either side.

For example, if I run my program on

```
"The dog was as wildly energetic as the old one. It was as bright as it has ever been."
```

the ideal output would be

```
"The dog was as wildly energetic as the old one"
"one. It was as bright as it has ever"
```

This should be an easy task, but I can't figure it out. (I'm pretty new to programming.) At first I tried to do this on word-tokenized versions of the text, but think that it may be easier to use regular expression on the raw string.

The best I could come up with is:

```
#FINDING __ AS __ AS __ PATTERNS

raw = "The dog was as wildly energetic as the old one. It was as bright as it has ever been."

import re

pattern_find = re.compile(r'\w* as \w* as \w*')    #Here we specify the regex code.

results = pattern_find.findall(raw)    #Here we do the search and put the results in a list.

print(results)
```

which outputs

```
['was as bright as it']
```

completely ignoring the case where there are two words between the two occurrences of "as". This was surprising to me since I thought that by including the asterisk `*` on `\w` it would capture arbitrarily long sequences of words. (What seems to be happening is that `\w*` is capturing arbitrary long strings of consecutive *characters*, rather than *words*.)

My questions are:

1. **How can I use regular expression to get what I want?**
2. **Is there a better way to achieve my desired result?**

<sub>**NOTE:** I know that I can use `concordance()` of NLTK to find single words with context, but it doesn't allow users to specify patterns of words. An alternative to using regular expression might involve building a function off of `concordance()`.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is the right tool for the job, though there are a few pitfalls. You have to make a pattern that captures 3 words of context *at most*, but fewer if there aren't 3 words.

This regex should do the trick:

```
(?:\S+\s+){,3}\b[aA]s(?:\s+\S+)+?\s+as\b(?:\s+\S+){,3}
```

---

Explanation:

```
(?:\S+\s+){,3}  # match a word, followed by space(s). Up to 3 times.
\b[aA]s         # assert word boundary and match "as"
(?:\s+\S+)+?    # match any number of words, but as few as possible
\s+             # followed by space(s)
as\b            # and another "as"
(?:\s+\S+){,3}  # match up to 3 more words
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Excellent explanation, but can you explain the function of the `?:` which begins the word-match portion of the regex? It has to do with naming groups?

Comment: @Silenus `?:` denotes a non-capturing group. It doesn't really matter in this pattern though, might as well have used normal capturing groups. Just a habit.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is a single word character, not an entire word. `\w*` will indeed match a single word (i.e. consecutive word characters). You should better use `\w+` though, to match *a single word character or more* rather than *zero word characters or more*.

So you may try to match more than a single word:

`\w+ \w+ \w+ as \w+ as \w+ \w+ \w+`

Or with an actual occurrences count:

`(\w+ ){3}as \w+ as (\w+ ){3}`

If you don't care how many words there are between the "as", you may match any number of occurrences:

`(\w+ ){3}as (\w+ )+as (\w+ ){3}`

A more advanced way to do this would be something like:

`(?:(?:\w+\s+)+as\s+){2}(?:\w+\s+)+`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Your "advanced way" seems to work for me, but when I plug in your other regex expressions, I get no output.

Comment: That's because I didn't omit the spaces between the expressions. So they're looking for "3 occurrences of some word characters followed by a space" and then "a space followed by 'as'". Will fix.